# Display the image in the django-tables2

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-tables2

#### settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

#### models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    image = models.ImageField()
```

#### tables.py

```
import django_tables2 as tables
from .models import Product

class ProductTable(tables.Table):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Product       
        fields = ("image" ,"name")
```

#### views.py

In the views.py , I filter the model objects and get QuerySet

```
import django_tables2 as tables
from .models import Product
from .tables import ProductTable

-----


table = ProductTable(new_objects)  #new_objects is Product QuerySet
return render(request, 'home.html', {'table': table })
```

#### Outcome

I got a table, but instead of images, only links. **How can I display the image?**

Comment: try add:
+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT ) in urls.py, take a look here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

Comment: @HudsonBarroso It did not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the docs, there is an example to subclass an img column.

https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/custom-data.html#subclassing-column

```
from django.utils.html import format_html

class ImageColumn(tables.Column):
    def render(self, value):
        return format_html('<img src="/media/img/{}.jpg" />', value)
```

You could also have a custom render function:

https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/custom-data.html#table-render-foo

```
def render_img_column(self, record, value):
    return mark_safe(f"<img src='{record.url}' />")
```